# Adding new column with values from two other columns - added conditionally

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have got such data frame:

[image: My Data Frame]

Short sample of data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'longitude':(-122.05, -118.30, -117.81), 'latitude':(37. 37, 34.26, 33.78)})
```

I need to add one more column "coordinates" where cell value is equal to:

> [lon]-122.05[lon] \n [lat] 37.37 [lat]

if there is longitude and latitude (sometimes there are None or "empty" values)

> [lon]-122.05[lon]

if there is no latitude value

> [B] No coordinates [B]

if there are no longitude and latitude values.

All new cells must be strings.

My code is here:

```
     def prepare_coords(df):
         def custom_edit(long, lat):  
            if not long.empty:
                long = "<lon>"+str(long.astype(str))+"</lon>"
            if not lat.empty:      
                lat = str(lat.astype(str))
                if lat.endswith("\n"):
                    lat.rstrip()
                lat = "<lat>"+lat+"</lat>"
            if len(long) > 1 and len(lat) > 1:  # Both: lon and lat
                return long + "\n" + lat            
            elif len(long) > 1:  # Only longitude
                return long
            else:
                return np.nan    # No longitude
            
        
        df["coordinates"] = ""
        df["coordinates"] = df["coordinates"].apply(custom_edit(df["longitude"], df["latitude"])).astype(str)
        return df                              
    
    
    df = prepare_coords(df)
```

But it gives me Atributte Error and "is not a valid function for 'Series' object" error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please paste your dataset as text instead of a image? It would help those who want to reproduce your problem

Comment: OK, I will do that

Comment: I provided "Short sample of data". Not much but should be enough for simple use.